# Better method for avoiding null in nested data with Java 7

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, null, retrofit

I have to analyze a huge data stream which often includes incomplete data. Currently the code is littered with null checks at multiple levels, as there could be incomplete data at any level.

So for example I might have to retrieve:
`Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName()`

I tried to create a method to try and reduce the null checks to a single method whereby I enter:

`IsValid(Model.getDestination(), Model.getDestination().getDevice(), Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName())`

this method fails because it evaluates all parameters before it sends them, rather than checking each at a time like
`Model.getDestination() != null && Model.getDestination().getDevice() != null && etc`

but is there a way I could pass in `Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName()` and do the check at each level without having to evaluate it or split it up before I pass it?

What I really want it to do is if there is a null/nullexception it should quietly return "", and continue processing incoming data

I know there are ways to do this elegantly in Java 8, but I am stuck with Java 7

Comment: You can make a quick implementation of `Optional` on your own, with only `orElseGet` and `map`, And a static `ofNullable`.

Comment: Oh yes, I also had that issue. Can you alter the classes in model? Then you could always create a full structure (perhaps on the fly on access, to patch null cases) and at each level introduce a getValue() method, which returns null if at any point in the path null occurs. e.g. if in `getDestination().getDevice().getName()` getDevice.Value() is already null, each subsequent navigation is still there (`.getDevice().getName()`) but e.g. `getName().getValue()`also returns null.

Comment: @RealSkeptic using java 7, implementing a `map` needs so much boilerplate because of the missing lambda syntax. It could get real messy, real fast.

Comment: If you are able to introduce dependencies to your project, you might be interested in using Guava (https://github.com/google/guava) or Functional Java (http://functionaljava.org). That way you could use their implementations of optional.

Comment: I actually solved this by modifying all the parent class getters (about 9 of them, including device, destination, cabletype, etc)) like güriösä suggested - thanks!!!

```if (thing == null){
    return new Thing();
}```
and using @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)
So parent data itself will never get a null, only an empty. It doesn't matter if child is empty. 
So no more validation, no more null checks, no exception checking, no extra navigation classes. I have a full structure when/if required - generated on the fly. So just return an empty class if requested then move along :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with a similar problem with deeply nested structures, and if I'd have had the opportunity to introduce additional structures just to navigate the underlying data, I think, I had done that.

This was C# which in the meantime has a save navigation/Elvis operator, for which we'll wait in vain with Java (proposed for Java 7 but [discarded](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359414/why-were-null-safe-operators-e-g-elvis-operator-rejected-as-part-of-java-7). Groovy has it btw.). Also looks like there are arguments [against using Elvis](https://www.theguild.nl/5-reasons-not-to-use-safe-navigation-operators/), even if you have it). Also lambdas (and extension methods) didn't improve things really. Also every other approach has been discredited as ugly in other posts here.

Therefore I propose a secondary structure purely for navigation, each element with a getValue() method to access the original structure (also the shortcuts proposed by @Michael are straight forward to add this way). Allowing you null save navigation like this:

```
 Model model = new Model(new Destination(null));

 Destination destination = model.getDestination().getValue(); // destination is not null
 Device device = model.getDestination().getDevice().getValue(); // device will be null, no NPE
 String name = destination.getDevice().getName().getValue(); // name will be null, no NPE

 NavDevice navDevice = model.getDestination().getDevice(); // returns an ever non-null NavDevice, not a Device
 String name = navDevice.getValue().getName(); // cause an NPE by circumventing the navigation structure
```

With straight forward original structures

```
    class Destination {

        private final Device device;

        public Destination(Device device) {
            this.device = device;
        }

        public Device getDevice() {
            return device;
        }
    }

    class Device {

        private final String name;

        private Device(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

And secondary structures for the purpose of save navigation.

Obviously this is debatable, since you always can access the original structure directly and run into a NPE. But in terms of readability perhaps I'd still take this, especially for large structures where a shrub of ifs or optionals really is an eyesore (which matters, if you have to tell, which business rules actually were implemented here).

A memory/speed argument could be countered by using only one navigation object per type and re-set their internals to approriate underlying objects as you navigate.

```
    class Model {

        private final Destination destination;

        private Model(Destination destination) {
            this.destination = destination;
        }

        public NavDestination getDestination() {
            return new NavDestination(destination);
        }
    }

    class NavDestination {

        private final Destination value;

        private NavDestination(Destination value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Destination getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public NavDevice getDevice() {
            return new NavDevice(value == null ? null : value.getDevice());
        }

    }

    class NavDevice {

        private final Device value;

        private NavDevice(Device value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Device getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public NavName getName() {
            return new NavName(value == null ? null : value.getName());
        }
    }

    class NavName {

        private final String value;

        private NavName(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 - if statement

You already provided it in your question. I think using am `if statement`like the following is perfectly acceptable:

```
Model.getDestination() != null && Model.getDestination().getDevice() != null && etc
```

---

### Option 2 - javax Validation and checking the result - before sending

You could make use of `javax validation`.

See: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

You would annotate the fields that you want with `@NotNull`.

Then you could use programmatic validation.

You could check the validation result to see if there is a problem.

**Example:**

So in your class you would do:

```
@NotNull
Public String Destination;
```

And you could feed your object to the validater:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<Model>> violations = validator.validate(Model);

for (ConstraintViolation<User> violation : violations) {
    log.error(violation.getMessage()); 
}
```

---

### Option 3 - fromNullable and Maps ( if you have Java 8)

I'm taking this one from https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255503/null-checking-whilst-navigating-object-hierarchies . This is very simular to your question.

```
import java.util.Optional;

Optional.fromNullable(model)
               .map(Model::getDestination)
               .map(Lounge::getDevice)
               .ifPresent(letter -> .... do what you want ...);
```

---

### Option 4 - Just using a try/catch

Everyone hates this one due to the slowness of exception.

Comment: if `Model.getDestination()` is NULL... how will `Model.getDestination().getDevice()` exist????

Answer (score 0):

So you want to simplify `Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName()`. First, I want to list a few things that should not be done: Don't use exceptions. Don't write an `IsValid` method, because it just doesn't work, because all functions (or methods) are strict in Java: that means that every time you call a function, all arguments are evaluated before they are passed to the function.

In Swift I would just write `let name = Model.getDestination()?.getDevice()?.getName() ?? ""`. In Haskell it would be like `name <- (destination >>= getDevice >>= getName) <|> Just ""` (assuming the Maybe monad). And this has different semantics from this Java code:

```
if(Model.getDestination() && Model.getDestination().getDevice() && Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName() {
    String name = Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName();
    System.out.println("We got a name: "+name);
}
```

because this snippet calls `getDestination()` 4 times, `getDevice()` 3 times, `getName()` 2 times. This has more than just performance implications: 1) It introduces race conditions. 2) If any of the methods have side-effects, you don't want them to be called multiple times. 3) It makes everything harder to debug.

The only correct way of doing it is something like this:

```
Destination dest = Model.getDestination();
Device device = null;
String name = null;
if(dest != null) {
    device = dest.getDevice();
    if(device != null) {
        name = device.getName();
    }
}
if(name == null) {
    name = "";
}
```

This code sets name to `Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName()`, or if any of these method calls return null, it sets name to "". I think correctness is more important than readability, especially for production applications (and even for example code IMHO). The above Swift or Haskell code is equivalent to *that* Java code.

If you have a production app, I guess that something like that is what you are already doing, because everything that is fundamentally different than that is error-prone.

**Every better solution has to provide the same semantics and it MUST not call any of the methods (getDestination, getDevice, getName) more than once.**

That said, I don't think you can simplify the code much with Java 7.

What you can do of course, is shorten the call chains: E.g. you could create a method `getDeviceName()` on `Destination`, if you need this functionality often. If this makes the code more readable depends on the concrete situation.

Forcing you to code on this low level also has advantages: you can do common subexpression elimination, and you'll see the advantages of it, because it will make the code shorter. E.g. if you have:

```
String name1 = Model.getDevice().getConnection().getContext().getName();
String name2 = Model.getDevice().getConnection().getContext().getLabel();
```

you can simplify them to

```
Context ctx = Model.getDevice().getConnection().getContext();
String name1 = ctx.getName();
String name2 = ctx.getLabel();
```

The second snippet has 3 lines, while the first snippet has only two lines. But if you unroll the two snippets to include null-checks, you will see that the second version is in fact much shorter. (I'm not doing it now because I'm lazy.)

Therefore (regarding Optional-chaining), Java 7 will make the code of the performance-aware coder look better, while many more high-level languages create incentives to make slow code. (Of course you can also do common subexpression elimination in higher level languages (and you probably should), but in my experience most developers are more reluctant to do it in high level languages. Whereas in Assembler, everything is optimized, because better performance often means you have to write less code and the code that you write is easier to understand.)

In a perfect word, we would all use languages that have built-in optional chaining, and we would all use it responsibly, without creating performance problems and race conditions.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `try-catch`. Because there is no processing required in your case, like

```
try{
    if(IsValid(Model.getDestination(), Model.getDestination().getDevice(), Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName())){

}catch(Exception e){
    //do nothing
}
```

Alternatively you can improve your `isValid` method by passing only `Model` object

```
boolean isValid(Model model){
    return (model != null && model.getDestination() != null && model.getDestination().getDevice() != null && model.getDestination().getDevice().getName() != null)
}
```

Comment: Relying on exceptions for normal program-flow is a really bad thing.

Comment: Also, IsValid still evaluates all arguments, so it is completely useless here.

Comment: @Michael, there is no problem in evaluating all arguments  in method, OP mentioned that he is passing all the values in method instead of Object and that is failing

Comment: @RahulAgrawal: What is the difference between 1) `IsValid(...)` and 2) `Model.getDestination().getDevice().getName()` ? Except that the first expression has worse performance and maybe even different semantics if the methods have side-effects.